# Find previous value of a DB record from transaction logs?

Tags: sql-server-2005, transactions

Trying to track down a bug in an application, but need to confirm whether a column value was changed on a particular record in SQL 2005.

How can I query the transaction logs for the record's previous column values?

Comment: Are you running in Full Recovery mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed it won't be easy. You can also investigate `fn_dblog`as in this post [Decoding a Simple Update Statement Within the Transaction Log](http://sqlfascination.com/2010/02/21/decoding-a-simple-update-statement-within-the-transaction-log/)

Answer (score 0):

Transaction logs aren't typically supposed to be directly queryable, but for exceptional circumstances, you can use the `DBCC LOG` command to get information from the transaction log. The output isn't exactly straightforward, and it would be a difficult task to determine whether a given column value was changed.

If you know the date of the change, it would probably be simpler to restore a copy of the database before and after the change to verify that the change was made.